# Info Path 2010 read and update accdb with Sharepoint Online

Tags: 2010, infopath, sharepoint-online, office-integration, microsoft-access

I am new to Sharepoint and to Info Path, so I hope can correctly articulate my goal, here.  I would like to use Info Path to distribute forms which read,update and delete records in an Access 2010 db which I have uploaded to a Sharepoint library.  I have found some online tutorials, which advised me to build a data connection file and upload it to my Sharepoint Library.  I have done this.  So my Sharepoint site has a library named "lib1" which contains 2 files-  "test_db.accdb" and "dataconnectionfile.udcx". I have approved both files as Sharepoint admin. Now, when I try to build an info path form, which I would like to query it's fields from the .accdb file, in my library, I always hit the same dead end.

> "This location does not contain any data connection files with the
>   appropriate settings."

If I use the Info Path form template "Data Connection File" and enter my sharepoint address (https://abc123.sharepoint.com) the Data Connection Wizard will find my library.  When I expand the library, I find the words

> "This location does not contain any data connection files with the
>   appropriate settings."

If I try to connect to the library, by using a blank form and adding a data connection, I reach the same result.

I sure could use some guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are myriad ways of screwing things.

**Please provide references to your statements:**

- "I have found some online tutorials, which advised me to build a data
  connection file and upload it to my Sharepoint Library"

All I could ever find is advising to put [UDCX files into sharepoint data connection library](https://sladescross.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/infopath-create-and-use-data-connection-library/).
But from your question it follows that you put it sharepoint form or document library.

- **about storing Microsoft Access database in a Sharepoint (form library)!?**
- aout using UDCX connection files for updating accdb?

While it is generally possible, the UDCX files are mainly and OOTB used for static queries.
[A database connection is always marked as ReadOnly](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/the-anatomy-of-a-udc-file) .
OOTB, the data connection from Infopath template to Microsoft Access database [is secondary which permit only quering](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-data-connection-to-a-microsoft-access-database-3897bf5d-59ef-44a2-a0ca-8c41f60be390?ocmsassetid=hp010097079&correlationid=febb6cf5-0287-4f34-9c23-82f2ea060ffe&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).
So, if you had not considered this from the very beginning, OOTB it is impossible to use created UDCX file for updating.

Also note that if you want to submit to a database, it cannot be done directly from web-enabled Infopath form, one should use a (data connection to a ) web service for this .

Before any hacking and inventing, I would advise you follow straight the existing tutorials on how to submit/update from Infopath form to Microsoft Access database:

- [Integrate an InfoPath Form with a Microsoft Access Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee526347%28v=office.14%29)
- [Submit Infopath form data to a Microsoft Access database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/submit-form-data-to-a-microsoft-access-database-e1ce3695-6204-4e89-8f89-4e26cc5f3b25?ocmsassetid=ha010211754&correlationid=a3ef7a9a-af71-4809-b4bd-627a3142af23&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
- [Leveraging Excel and Access Services in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh181577%28v=msdn.10%29)
- [Change the main data connection to another Microsoft Access database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-main-data-connection-to-another-microsoft-access-database-12376f25-3f74-407e-8ca5-53409cc2bcc3?ocmsassetid=hp010096925&correlationid=342c4b71-6c24-4582-87ef-80e055ef3420&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 0):

If you create your InfoPath form as "Database enabled" you cannot Publish it to SharePoint (it only supports publishing tight to a Content type or in a form-library).

On the other hand if you only interested in keeping data "online" you could simply design other lists as secondary sources of data and use those in your design.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You wrote `(it only supports publishing tight to a Content type or in a form-library)`  Can you please link further information? I don't really understand.