# Info path forms

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online, access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Info Path 2010 read and update accdb with Sharepoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57322/info-path-2010-read-and-update-accdb-with-sharepoint-online)

Can an info path form in a Sharepoint library update an access database in the same library?

Infopath 2010, sharepoint online, Access 2010.

Comment: I believe you asked [the same](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57322/info-path-2010-read-and-update-accdb-with-sharepoint-online/57627#57627) before. Don't you think that you are asking something weird - of putting one database management system (Microsoft Access) under control of another data management system (Sharepoint)? You should decide between eiher one or another!